# Problem with getting into the next input - guessing game in Python

Tags: python

I have a problem with going into next question my guessing game.

How I can do it? I really tried but i don't have any idea.

```
def guessingGame():
    anwsers = ["Kononowicz", "Suchodolski"]
    questionTries = 3
    questionTriesCounter = 0

    while questionTriesCounter < questionTries:
         firstQuestion = input("What is the surname of famous president from Bialystok? ")
         if firstQuestion == anwsers[0]:
            secondQuestion = input("What is the nick")
         else:
            questionTriesCounter+= 1
         if questionTriesCounter == questionTries:
            print('game over.')


guessingGame()
```

Comment: write `print (firstQuestion)` just before line `if firstQuestion == answers[0]` and share the output. I believe you are missing something there.

Comment: You might be better off putting the questions and answers together: `qa = [("What is the surname...", "Kononowicz"), ("What is the nick", "Suchodolski")]`. Then use a loop over this list.

Comment: If you're using python 2, you might want to change `input()` to `raw_input()`. Other than that, I can't see anything _wrong_ right now

Comment: python 3.7.3 version

Answer (score 0):

You can put your questions into a while loop and use a function to generically process questions like the following:

```py
def question(question, questionTries, answer, questionTriesCounter):
    guess = ""   
    while (questionTriesCounter > questionTries and guess != answer):
        guess = input(question)
        questionTries += 1
    return [guess == answer, questionTries]


def guessingGame():
    anwsers = ["Kononowicz", "Suchodolski"]
    questionTriesCounter = 3
    questionTries = 0

    firstQuestion = question("What is the surname of famous president from Bialystok? ",
                             questionTries,
                             anwsers[0],
                             questionTriesCounter)

    if firstQuestion[0] == True:
        secondQuestion = question("What is the nick? ",
                                  questionTries,
                                  anwsers[1],
                                  questionTriesCounter)

        if secondQuestion[0] == True:
            print("Congrats you won!")        
        else:
            print('game over. maximum number of trials reached!')    
    else:
        print('game over. maximum number of trials reached!')


guessingGame()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks to work atleast in python3. It would help yourself to input some print lines to see where your code is at and to tell the player what is happening

```
def guessingGame():
anwsers = ["5", "1"]
questionTries = 3
questionTriesCounter = 0

while questionTriesCounter < questionTries:
     firstQuestion = input("What is 1 + 4 ")
     print(firstQuestion)
     if firstQuestion == anwsers[0]: 
        secondQuestion = input("what is 5 - 4")
        if secondQuestion == anwsers[1]:
            print("Game won.")
            break
     else:
        questionTriesCounter+= 1
        print (f'Wrong answer. You have used {questionTriesCounter} of {questionTries} tries')
     if questionTriesCounter == questionTries:
        print('game over.')
```

guessingGame()

The game works like this and prints out the answer in console to better assist in seeing which point the game is currently at